# how to take picture(snapshot) while video been recorded using surface view

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview, image

I am done with recording video with surface view. Now I want to know "how to take picture(snapshot) while video been recorded using surface view" ?? Can anyone help me please.! What needs to I add in **mycam** button to take picture ??

```
public class ActiveCam extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
  boolean recording = false;
  MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
  SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
  Button myStart;
  Button myStop;
  Button mycam;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recording = false;
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    initMediaRecorder();
    setContentView(R.layout.camact); //This is my XML file

    Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    myStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myStart.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
    myStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myStop.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener1);
    mycam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mycam.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener3);

  }
  private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener1 = new  Button.OnClickListener()
  {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
        //finish();
    }

  };
Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()  
{  
    @Override  
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)  
    {  
        //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap  
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);  
        //set the iv_image  
        Toast.makeText(ActiveCam.this,"cap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);  
    }  
};  

private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener3 = new Button.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {

        //I need to take picture after pressing this button...What I needs to add    here??? 

    }

};      
private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
       mediaRecorder.start();
   recording = true;
   myStop.setText("STOP");
    }
 };
 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prepareMediaRecorder();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void initMediaRecorder()
{
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/your.mp4");
     //mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(..set size..); 
}
private void prepareMediaRecorder()
{
  mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
  try 
  {
     mediaRecorder.prepare();
  }
  catch (IllegalStateException e) 
  {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

This is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="Start" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      android:text="Pause" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="500px"
    android:layout_height="500px"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="Button" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecordingView [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107270/Recording-and-Playing-Video-on-Android) & [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html).You can take snapshot by this [code](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/07/how-to-take-screenshot-of-your-phone-in-android-through-code/) 
If you have an videoView in your xml than you have to make linearLayout as its parent(videoView as child of linearLayout) and when you will save linearlayout image that means you will be saving your videoview image .

Try this and read that code i have send to take snapshot.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:text="Start" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
          android:text="Pause" />

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="120dip"
    android:text="Take Screenshot"
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />
    </LinearLayout>
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Button" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help

Add this on Button3 Listner

```
private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener3 = new Button.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {

        //I need to take picture after pressing this button...What I needs to add    here??? 
        //View v1 = L1.getFocusedChild();
        L1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bm = L1.getDrawingCache();
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
    }

};
```

Change your Surface manager widht and heigh

```
<SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="400px"
            android:layout_height="400px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
```

and add `android:background="#FF0000"` in you linear layout

it will help you to figure out that does ur snapshot code works or not

Comment: Can you please able to tel exact change I need to modify with my above edited code.!!! Thanks

Comment: I posted my XML file. Please check

Comment: Thanks. I added the below codes that u sent on that link. It sets search icon on the imageview not the captured image. Can you please tel me how to implement it. 
`View v1 = L1.getRootView();
          v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm); 
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);`

Comment: @Aruva i have edited xml code. i have added ImageView above LinearLayout. what it will do when you will capture image than this ImageView will show you snapshot. You have to add above code( View v1 = L1.getRootView(); and so on till end) on button click. and than see it ImageView is displaying any image. if it doesnt work try that code about snapshot in another project see if its working or not

Comment: Your code works once the image is captured. I am using media recorder, It will record video. If i need to take picture while recording video what I need to add over in the button click with your code. This is my question. I hope you understand the question.!!! 

I am unable to use chat.

Comment: than how you want to take snapshot ? on button click? i didnt understand how u will take picture.

Comment: Is there any option to take picture while recording video like `mediaRecorder.takepicture();` If there so that I can add it over in my button click and use your code to view it.

Comment: @Aruva try it now. i can successfully take my screen snapshot. i dont have video in my sdcard so i could try it by playing video and then taking snapshot.

Comment: It captures the whole screen. I need the exact surface view part. Have you tried that???

Comment: @Aruva have you comment this View v1 = L1.getRootView();? just use L1. it will take snapshot of surfacemanager. i have tried it and wokring for me

Comment: Super. Its capturing the image but the captured image is fully black. Is there any other way to sort out..??

Comment: hmm. use surfaceview instead of L1. and take snapshot of surfaceview

Comment: Yes you can. but you should post it as another question. tick this as answer. as you can take snapshot now. thanks

Comment: Still I have problem in taking picture of surface view. If I use `View v1 =myVideoView;` it not at all showing image in Image view. So I again tried with `View v1=surfaceview.getRootView();` It captures the whole frame but the the image in surface view still remains black. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: i said in my previous comment that comment that line view v1 = myVideoView. just take snapshot of l1. not that videoview.

Comment: If I use L1 still the captured image is black.

Comment: @Zohaib, it's really doesn't work. I have 2 phones with API 14 and API 21. They are both saving black image only.

Comment: @L'Esperanza It will be really hard for me to help you.I am not working on Android anymore so I cant test it on my computer. :(